# Getting real file name case on a case-insensitive file system on Linux/OSX/BSD/Solaris

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

I am looking for a way to look up real case of a file name on a case-preserving, case-insensitive file system on all Unix derivatives.

On Windows you have FindFirstFile.

I can see F_GETPATH variant of fnctl on OSX, yet I am not sure if this does what I am looking for (I don't have a way to test this).

The research I've done so far:

1. stat syscall seems to return whatever was given to the stat call
2. lsof and /proc seems to resolve the descriptor back to the that was provided in an fopen syscall.

I know this can be done with a recursive readdir, but for a path with N levels, that would be many syscalls potentially ending up expensive.

I am looking for a cheaper way to do this.

This is an example to illustrate the case:

```
root@you:/mnt/fat32# mkdir -p Case/Sensitive
root@you:/mnt/fat32# touch Case/Sensitive/file
root@you:/mnt/fat32# stat case/sensitive/file
  File: case/sensitive/file
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 840h/2112d      Inode: 33          Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-06-21 20:27:36.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2020-06-21 20:27:36.000000000 +0100
Change: 2020-06-21 20:27:36.000000000 +0100
 Birth: -

root@you:/mnt/fat32# find .
.
./Case
./Case/Sensitive
./Case/Sensitive/file
```

Note that stat'ing the file returns the input case, not the case in which the file is stored.

Find does return the real case of the file but it does that because it
recursively lists children of every directory up to where the file is stored.

This would be expensive for deeply nested items located in directories with many children, hence I am looking for a cheaper way to do this.

Ideally something that can either return the "stored" case, given a file descriptor or a path that might have the wrong case.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].  Or at least a sample directory and files structure with the cases you want, and the output you want.  Linux standard filesystems implementations are case-preserving and case-insensitive.  Same for AIX, Solaris, HPUX, SystemV, ...  Now to *look up real case of a file name*?!?  You mean like search for a particular pattern in the filename?  Then look up `find`, it dies exactly that.  More details will help.

Comment: Added an example as requested.